# capture data from input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Have been trying to collect the data entered into input fields that have NOT been submitted and post that data into another div buy pressing a button.

1. Can this be achieved with script?

Html

```
<form>
    <div class="div1"><input type="text" name="data1"></div>

    <div class="div2"><input type="text" name="data2"></div>

    <div class=submitformbutton" type="submit" name="submit" ></div>

</form>


<div class="capture_button"></div>
<div class="divoutput"> list data captured here </div>
```

Comment: How do you know what data has not been submitted?

Comment: Why do you need AJAX to move data from one part of the page to another? And, where is the `form` that will have its data submitted? And, why not use a `button` for your button?

Comment: I wouldnt know what data has, its just so the data that has been submitted, instead of submitting it  would like to take the data from the fields without submitting it.

Comment: Why the harsh voting down, is this not a place questions if you dont know something. so much effort in degrading peoples posts these days instead of helping people explore further.

Comment: The down vote is because you haven't clearly stated what you are trying to do and you didn't initially post all the relevant code. We can't help you if we can't understand what you are asking.

Comment: So, do you want data submitted somewhere or do you simply want the data to move from one area to another. What has your question got to do with AJAX?

Comment: I thought it may be possible to do it with ajax or jquery or javascript. Yes the data would be posted into the bottom div called "divoutput"

Comment: This would be achieved by pressing another button first (not the submit button) or if it can be do live with out pressing a button even better.

Comment: If you are just talking about moving data within the page, there is no submit, AJAX or POST happening. It's a simple copying of data. See my answer to that below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is still unclear what you are trying to do, but this will simply move the data out of the input fields an into your output area. There is no AJAX or form submission needed to do this.

```js
// Get references to the DOM elements we'll need to use
var frm = document.querySelector("form");
var capBtn = document.querySelector(".capture_button");
var out = document.querySelector(".divoutput");

// Set up click event handler for capture button
capBtn.addEventListener("click", function(){
  var outputString = "<ul>";

  // Loop through form elements and write data to output area
  for(var i = 0; i < frm.elements.length; i++){
    // Ignore the submit button
    if(frm.elements[i].type !== "submit"){
      outputString += "<li>" + frm.elements[i].name + " = " + frm.elements[i].value + "</li>";
    }
  }
  
  out.innerHTML = outputString + "</ul>";
  
  // Show the submit button for further processing
  document.querySelector(".submitformbutton").classList.remove("hidden");
  
  // Hide the capture button
  this.classList.add("hidden");
});
```

```css
.capture_button { 
  border:1px solid black;
  background-color:#e0e0e0;
  display:inline-block;
  margin:5px 0;
  padding:3px;
  cursor:pointer;
}

.hidden { visibility:hidden; }
```

```html
<div>
  <form>
    <div class="div1"><input type="text" name="data1"></div>

    <div class="div2"><input type="text" name="data2"></div>

    <button class="submitformbutton hidden" type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>

<div>
  <span class="capture_button">Capture the form data</span>
  <div class="divoutput"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this script.

```
$(".capture_button").click(function() {
     var data1 = $("[name='data1']").val();
     var data2 =  $("[name='data2']").val();

     $(".divoutput").append(data1+ " " + data2);//or you can use html instead of append

});
```

I hope, this script will solve your problem.

Comment: "undefined" comes up. the form has not been submitted yet does this script still grab the data from the input fields

Comment: how to use html instead

Comment: $(div).html(data);. You must give id to your input element. And grab the data from element with id name . For example $("#id_name").val();